# SAPUI5 view table gets cut off

Tags: javascript, xml, html, sapui5

In my SAPUI5 project, my table gets cut off. I am pretty sure that this is because the height of my div is not handling that size, but I am unable to change it dynamically according to my view's height.

[image: Scroll ends there, the table gets cut]
*(Scroll ends there, the table gets cut)*

My index.html contains the following:

```
<!-- Right Sidebar -->
<section class="c1" >
  <div id="content"></div>
</section>
```

I am placing my view inside the "content" div.

```
function loadView() {
  var app = new sap.m.App({
    initialPage: "idViewTest1"
  });
  var page = sap.ui.view({
    viewName: "myViews.viewTest",
    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
  });
  app.addPage(page);
  app.placeAt("content");
}
```

Then, I have my view with some graphs and a table

```
<Page showHeader="false" enableScrolling="false">
  <VBox>
    <viz:VizFrame xmlns="sap.viz" id="idcolumn" vizType="line"</viz:VizFrame>
    <Table
      id="idTable"
      items="{/itemsTest}"
      class="sapUiSizeCompact"
      width= "50%">
      <columns>
        <Column width= "60%">
          <Text text="Description"/>
        </Column>
        <Column width= "40%">
          <Text text="Value"/>
        </Column>
      </columns>
      <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
          <cells></cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
      </items>
    </Table>
  </VBox>
</Page>
```

And finally, I have the controller:

```
onInit: function() {
  var oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("idcolumn");
  //code to populate the vizframe
  var oTable = this.byId("idTable");
  //code to populate the table
}
```

Comment: I will be helpful if you share the screenshot as well.

Comment: @inzio screenshot added

Comment: Update the property `enableScrolling="true"` in your VIEW ie.., `<Page showHeader="false" enableScrolling="true">` this is add scroll to the page. And table will not cut off.

Answer (score 2):

As per your code

```
<Page showHeader="false" enableScrolling="false">
```

The table is cutting off because the page scrolling is disabled.

Solution:

- Remove `enableScrolling` property: `<Page showHeader="false">` OR
- Update `enableScrolling` property to `true`:  `<Page showHeader="false" enableScrolling="true">`

Comment: Thanks Inizio, but I don't want to create a new scroll inside the view. I want to keep the main scroll. Does it make sense?

Comment: Kindly share the complete VIEW.